# Get PFN from DMA address (dma_addr_t)?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to get the PFN associated with a memory block allocated with `dma_alloc_coherent` for use with a PCIe device as shown below:

```c
unsigned long pfn;

buffer = dma_alloc_coherent(&pcie->dev, size, &bus_addr, GFP_KERNEL);

// Get PFN?
virt_to_phys(buffer) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
```

I'm aware that this is probably not the correct method, but it seems to work... I'm just looking for the right solution to translate the potential bus address (since I do not know if there is an IOMMU) to a PFN. Thanks in advance.

Note: There seems to be an ARM function in the kernel called `dma_to_pfn`, which seems to be exactly what I need, but for x86.

Comment: I think correct way is to traverse via PFNs and compare necessary information. May I ask why do you need that? And yes, IOMMU may do interesting things which won't allow you to do the above (when bounce buffers in use, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is indeed wrong. From the man page for [`virt_to_phys()`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/linux-manual-3.16/virt_to_phys.9.en.html):

> This function does not give bus mappings for DMA transfers. In almost all conceivable cases a device driver should not be using this function.

The equivalent function for DMA addresses is [`dma_to_phys()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/dma-direct.h#L63), defined in `include/linux/dma-direct.h` as follows:

```c
phys_addr_t dma_to_phys(struct device *dev, dma_addr_t daddr);
```

Therefore you can do:

```c
dma_to_phys(&pcie->dev, bus_addr) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
```

Notice that I am using the `bus_addr` returned by `dma_alloc_coherent()`, not `buffer`, since you obviously need to pass a DMA address (`dma_addr_t`) to this function, not a virtual address.

There also seems to be a macro [`PHYS_PFN()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pfn.h#L22) defined in `include/linux/pfn.h` to get the PFN for a given physical address, if you prefer to use that:

```c
PHYS_PFN(dma_to_phys(&pcie->dev, bus_addr));
```